# Django jQuery $.ajax() is not a function using full build cdn

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I building a quiz app and when I press a button I want an AJAX request to go to my backend, however it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (10:26)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

I am aware that above it says that I am using the slim build of jQuery, but this is not the case as I am using the following CDN from the jQuery website:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The jQuery code I am using for this function is below and it is located in the head of the HTML document below the CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#edit-confirm").on("click", function() {
            console.log("click");
            $.ajax ({

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

All other jQuery works and the "click" is shown in the console when I press the button right before the error message.

Comment: Hi , did you check if there is any other jquery cdn added because it shows `jquery-3.2.1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone!

It turns out that the problem was Bootstrap's slim build was overriding the full build I was using since Bootstrap puts their CDN at the bottom of the body in the template on their website (does anyone know why?). Once I deleted that, everything was fine.